# Foreach array explode amount total amount

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array  i need to add all amounts if they are in together eg 1000|1000

```
  Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [student_no] => 8080808128
                [amt] => 1000|1000
                [main_receipt] => M_0000000001
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [student_no] => 8080808128
                [amt] => 500
                [main_receipt] => M_312312321
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [student_no] => 8569544855
                [amt] => 500
                [main_receipt] => M_000000026
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [student_no] => 9172544146
                [amt] => 1000
                [main_receipt] => M_00000001234
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [student_no] => 9541256358
                [amt] => 1000|1000|500
                [main_receipt] => M_000000022
            )

        [5] => stdClass Object
            (
                [student_no] => 9892469054
                [amt] => 1000
                [main_receipt] => M_0000000002
            )

    )

$newar=0;
foreach($fa as $key){

       $temp= explode('|',$key->amt);
foreach($temp as $tem =>$va){
echo $va."<br>";
  $newar += $va;
    $array[]=$newar;
```

im trying to construct a new array  where the amt is totaled

for eg

```
[0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [student_no] => 8080808128
                    [amt] => 2000
                    [main_receipt] => M_0000000001
                )
  [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [student_no] => 8080808128
                    [amt] => 500
                    [main_receipt] => M_312312321
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [student_no] => 8569544855
                    [amt] => 500
                    [main_receipt] => M_000000026
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [student_no] => 9172544146
                    [amt] => 1000
                    [main_receipt] => M_00000001234
                )
```

notice how in the [0] key array the amount value totaled. Im trying to construt this type of an array  but i cant seem to get the logic .......

I am aware that my current logic is just adding the values per key of array

Comment: Please add example what have you tried.

Comment: array_sum(explode('|', $obj->amt))?

Comment: @Eihwaz.  I'll try that....

Comment: @SCC I HAVE. BELOW THE FIRST ARRAY IV PROVIDED

Comment: So whats your issue?

Comment: I'm trying  @Eihwaz method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split your amt when | appears and calculate the sum using **array_sum()**

```
foreach($data as &$array) {
   $array->amt = array_sum(explode('|', $array->amt));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `$newar` back to `0` before looping through the exploded amount. Otherwise, you're adding the amounts from all the objects together. You can also just use `array_sum()` to total all the elements of the exploded amount.

And if you want objects in the new array, you need to create objects, not just store the total in the array.

```
foreach ($fa as $obj) {
    $temp = explode('|', $obj->amt);
    $newar = array_sum($temp);
    $newobj = clone $obj;
    $newobj->amt = $newar;
    $array[] = $newobj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your goal:

> "to construct a new array where the amt is totaled"

use the following solution with `array_map`, `strpos`(to check if there's a delimiter `|` within `amt` property to avoid redundant splitting) and `array_sum` functions:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$new_arr = array_map(function($obj){
    $obj->amt = (strpos($obj->amt, "|") !== false)? array_sum(explode("|", $obj->amt)) : $obj->amt;
    return $obj;
}, $arr);

print_r($new_arr);
```